# Dart2Js generated code doesn't access Google cloud endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

It's strange. The code works well in Chromium -- after authorization (oauth2), visit the Google cloud endpoints to download information. But once it's converted to js and opened in Chrome , after authorization, it never visits the cloud endpoints then (checked from Google app engine log). 
If it's opened in IE9, even the authorization page never show up. 
Any help is appreciated.

Source Code:
example.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>example</h1>
 <div id="container">   
         <div id="title">
             <p>Hello!</p>    
          </div>    
          <div id="navigation">
              <p> first </p>            
          </div>
         <div id="content">
              <p> Content </p>            
         </div>
     <button id="login">Login</button>
</div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="example.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.css

```dart
#navigation {

  float:left;
  color: #333;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;

}
#content {
 margin-left: 200px;
   width: 600px;
  height: 600px;

  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

example.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import "packages/dart_terminalendpoint_v1_api_client/lib/terminalendpoint_v1_api_browser.dart" as gdglib;
import "package:google_plus_v1_api/plus_v1_api_browser.dart" as pluslib;
import "package:google_oauth2_client/google_oauth2_browser.dart";
final CLIENT_ID = "----------.apps.googleusercontent.com";
final SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"];

void main() {
  var auth = new GoogleOAuth2(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES);
  var gdg = new gdglib.Terminalendpoint(auth);
  var plus = new pluslib.Plus(auth);      
  var navigation = query("#navigation");
  var content = query("#content");
  var loginButton = query("#login");
  pluslib.Person me;

  void fetch() {
    gdg.makeAuthRequests=true;
    gdg.terminals.listTerminal().then((l) {
      navigation.text = "";
      if (l.items != null) {
        l.items.forEach((e) {
          var p = new ParagraphElement();
          p.text = " ${e.emailAddress}: ${e.location}";
          navigation.append(p);
        });
      }
    });
   }
  loginButton.onClick.listen((Event e) {
  fetch();
});
```

}

Comment: it's a bit unclear.. you have to be a bit more specific to get an answer.. try to isolate your code to the minimum and maybe having some snippets here.. in this current form this question is very vague..

Comment: Thanks. attached the source code too.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Vincent did the lastest version solve this issue for you? http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/discovery_api_client_generator

Comment: just downloaded the latest one [from github](https://github.com/dart-gde/discovery_api_dart_client_generator) to generate the endpoint client lib. The problem is still there. Chromium works fine but the generated js in Chrome26 or IE9 doesn't visit Google app engine. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used discovery_api_client_generator, and it works great. However, by default it is set to not authenticate, because a variable in the library is set to false, and there is no way to change it from outside. If you manually edit the generated library in the file client_base.dart, the code in browser_client.dart below, will do the 'right' thing, which is to call authenticate.

```dart
if (makeAuthRequests && auth != null) {
  auth.authenticate(request).then((request) => request.send(body));
} else {
  request.send(body);
}
```